# Game theory and antagonistic games in trading

Tags: money-management, game-theory

In one of the topic here, particularly in the comments, i saw a link to the page describing connection between Antagonistic Games and finances but i cannot find it now and would appreciate if somebody could remind me where it was ... seems that SE search does not search for a keyword in comments.

> Also one of the suggestions in game theory claims that : 
>   if there are two losing games then there is mix of them that can be winning.

**Questions :**

1. Could anyone suggest a possible combination of such games in trading
   or at least give a tip about which side of trading can rely on
   mentioned suggestion - prediction, money management, etc?
2. Could i ask you to point me to some useful resources dedicated to
   the application of Game Theory in real life?